# Laravel route isn't working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

i'm new to laravel, still learning, and i have 2 routes with controllers and function index

this is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('accessories', 'ProductsController@index');
```

the first one works well but i don't know why the second doesn't:

Not Found

The requested URL /laravel/public/accessories was not found on this server.

thanks.

Comment: Have you copied the supplied `.htaccess` file in that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access yourwebsite.com/index.php/accessories

Comment: yeahh that was it.. now i'll see how i can take off that index, thank you :D